# SSL isn't working with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

I was trying to install a SSL certificate on my VPS. I Generated the CSR, and Got the Certificate and Intermediate CA. I am working on apache 2 on ubuntu server 13.10. So I used the Default SSL virtual host in `sites-available` and configured the `default-ssl` according to the Certificate vendor company instruction. Here is what i did,

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.buysellswapit.com
    DocumentRoot /sites/bswapit
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /sites/bswapit>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile    /var/ssl/www_buysellswapit_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ssl/www_buysellswapit_com.key

    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/ssl/www_buysellswapit_com_im.crt

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
     BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And then Reloaded the apache, Nothing happened. Then I thought about checking the configuration loading through apache, and it was `apache2.conf`, Although i didn't make any change on `apache2.conf` . Then i check the `port.conf` and made it to listen on 443 port ! Reloaded the apache, and for safety, Restarted it. The Same again ! SSL isn't working !

Here is the `port.conf` file,

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

  Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
  Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Now, What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Anything in your logs?

Comment: nope, Nothing relevant !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the **ssl module**:

`a2enmod ssl`

then enable the **ssl virtual host**:

`a2ensite default-ssl`

**or**:

`cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled && ln -s ../sites-available/default-ssl`

and:

`service apache2 restart`

Comment: Did all of that ! Default-ssl is enabled but server isn't responding with https !

Comment: Even running `a2enmod ssl` and restarting apache?

Comment: God damn, the answer was always in front of my eyes and i didn't saw it. Forgot to enable SSL Module. Thanks Man.

Comment: These things happen. You're welcome!